# bootstrap tabs justify with badge on small screen jump to second row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, badge, justify

i have sample code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">15</span></a></li>
```

i have problem with badge is screen is smaller badge jump to second row, and this is what i don't want

working demo on http://jsfiddle.net/twvqxtgw/ 
i tried with float and etc but nothing working :/ still jump to second row
also on big screen title with badge in center of tab

Thanks!

Comment: You can use padding-left css to change title position..

Comment: screen size can be dynamic... also title is changing from title to * title